# Bars of my chartjs chart has no background color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using a bar chart from chart.js. Everything just work fine except for the bars. They don't have a background color, even not the default. I can see the top border of the chart and when I', hovering over the bar I see the tooltip with the value.

This is the code I use:

````
        var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['< 30', '30 - 60', '61 - 90', '> 90'],
                datasets: [{
                        label: "sales",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                        borderWidth: '0',
                        data: [40, 60, 70, 70]
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                barStrokeWidth : 10,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false ,
                            color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)'
                        },
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,
                            color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            callback: function(value) {
                                return value + ',00'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        tension: 0
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
            }
        });```

An idea how I can solve my problem?
````

Comment: [your code in codepen](https://codepen.io/pratik-sangami/pen/KKPRbwZ).
This it the exact code of yours, i see the color specified.
Try adding a working fiddle or codepen link.

Comment: That's because you've set the default color `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',`, try and include the colors inside the data set https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/ktb38o1j/

Comment: It's really strange that the bars not working. Even the tooltip shows a label with the background colors but the bar itself don't work. Borders of the bars are working as well. Probably the problem is caused by another conflicting stylesheet or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example based on previous comments

```js
var mixedChart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['< 30', '30 - 60', '61 - 90', '> 90'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "sales",
      borderWidth: '0',
      data: [40, 60, 70, 70],
      backgroundColor: ["#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#ff0000", "#0000ff"],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    barStrokeWidth: 10,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          callback: function(value) {
            return value + ',00'
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's really strange that the bars not working. Even the tooltip shows a label with the background colors but the bar itself don't work. Borders of the bars are working as well. Probably the problem is caused by another conflicting stylesheet or javascript

Comment: If the above snippet works for you, you should follow the code!

Comment: Well the snippet is working except for the bars. They don't have a color but I can't figure out why not. Everything else is working fine